# Display all message notification using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm using AJAX to display messages notification , but the problem is that if i send two messages to a specific user at the same time , he receive just the latest one .
this is my_js.js file:

```
function updatess() {
     $.getJSON("php/fetch.php", function(data) {
       $.each(data.result, function(){
        var name = this['sender_name'];
        var message = this['message'];

       $( '#messages' ).attr( 'id', 'new_msgs' );       
    $('div.from_name').html( name );
    $('div.message').html( message );
   });
 });
}
```

and this is my index page:

```
<div id="msg_holder" style=" overflow-x:scroll ;overflow-y: hidden; position:fixed;height:45px;width:865px;background-color:yellow;bottom:0px; left:144px; ">
<div class="mess_test" style="width:165px; height:35px; background:blue; bottom:0px; left:144px; margin-right: 16px">
<div class="from_name" style="float:left; "></div>
<div class="message" style="float:right;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.html()` will reset the HTML of your elements, you're probably want to use **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** instead:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element
>   in the set of matched elements.

So you can change:

```
$('div.from_name').html( name );
$('div.message').html( message );
```

to:

```
$('div.from_name').append( name );
$('div.message').append( message );
```

Comment: thanks , but thats work if two messages comes from one user ,if that two messages comes from a different users , it gives me something like message_from: user_one message_from: user_two message: hi message: hello , i mean the two messages appear on one window , what i want is to appear in different windows.